# Login with requests

Tags: python

My code doesn't sign me in

```
            url = 'https://www.codecademy.com/login?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.codecademy.com%2F'
        values = {'user[login]': email,
                  'user[password]': password}
        r = requests.post(url, data=values)

        b =requests.get('https://www.codecademy.com/learn')
        print b.text
```

It just prints out the login/signup page source. Any help would be appreciated!Btw this is just a test site. If any other ways to do it it would be appreciated!

Comment: Because the redirection is made via JavaScript, I suppose

Comment: Remove the redirect parameter from your url variable. It's not needed. The form logon URL is simply `https://www.codecademy.com/login`